# Numpy - Use values as index of another arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I face a problem with Numpy, I try to use the values of each row (of B) as the indexes of another multidimensional array (A):

```
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> B
    array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 1,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> np.clip(B, 0, 2)
    array([[0, 1, 2, 2],
           [1, 2, 2, 2],
           [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Here is the expected result:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 2],
       [4, 5, 5, 5],
       [8, 8, 8, 8]])
```

Any idea ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `np.clip` just clips (i.e. clamps) the values of each element of an array, so in your case it would clip the values to between 0 and 2. Why do you expect that result from np.clip(...)?

Comment: Hi XPhyro. Because length of rows in 'A' is 3, so indexes need to be between 0 and 2. So i supposed that np.clip is the first step to answer my question.

Comment: What you're doing here is just clipping the values of the elements of `B` so that they are in the closed range `[0, 2]`; therefore, it is impossible for `np.clip` to return an array that has elements valued outside this range, which is what you expect it to do (looking by the values 4, 5 and 8 in the last two rows of the expected result). I suspect `np.clip` is not what you want. Can you elaborate what exactly you're trying to do here, perhaps with steps? I could not understand much just from the question itself.

Comment: My question is perhaps ambiguous indeed, i'm sorry ... Let us consider the result of np.clip as being already 'B'. I want to replace the values in each line by their correspondence in A. For example, the last line is filled with '2', so we replace them with '8', the value at index 2 of the last line of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for `np.take_along_axis`:

```
A = np.array([
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]]
)
B = np.array([
           [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 1,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]
)
C = np.clip(B, 0, 2)

res = np.take_along_axis(A, C, 1)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = np.clip(B, 0, 2)
for i, row in enumerate(result):
    for j, elem in enumerate(row):
        result[i][j] = A[i][elem]
```

After [@hilberts_drinking_problem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4585963/hilberts-drinking-problem)'s answer, I have done some benchmarks using `timeit`. The answers, when tested with `10,000,000 loops` took `103s` and `82s`, the latter being mine. Therefore, if your data is small but if you are going to be looping over it quite a lot, I would recommend you to use my answer. If such is not the case, I believe the convenience of hilberts_drinking_problem's answer makes it superior. For more information, see the comments to this answer.

Note that in both cases, I tested just the parts after clipping, meaning the preceding preparation part does not interfere with the benchmark.

Comment: Probably a working answer, but i was looking for a "vectorised" solution :/ There is no possibilities ?

Comment: By a vectorised solution, do you mean that the result should be in a vector form, or that the result should be computed via a series of vector operations?

Comment: Vectorized operations, so by using numpy functions only

Comment: As a side comment on the benchmark, I would expect better performance from `numpy` as `A` and `B` get larger. For example, with `n = 100; A = B = np.random.randint(0, 100, (n, n))`, I see a 70x speedup for `numpy`. If `A` and `B` remain small, while the number of iterations becomes large, Python `for` loops may be viable. At this point, one may consider using `numba`.

Comment: The numpy solution was the best for me because i have 250 millions rows with 6 columns.

Comment: You are correct, I edited my answer to reflect it better. @hilberts_drinking_problem